# Avoiding cookies while requesting static content

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webserver

I just did an audit of one of my web application page (built using ASP.Net and running on development server) using Google chrome's developer tool. One particular warning caught my eyes:

**Serve static content from a cookieless domain (5)**!

I would like to know is it possible to avoid cookies for these kind of requests. I see that there is no cookie requests for javascript files as well. I  it possible to avoid cookies in the header for these files as well? and why didn't the browser attach cookies for javascript files and attach for CSS and image?

Comment: Could you fix the image, or remove the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie are "attached" to a domain and a path. If you set cookies for a path above your files, they'll be sent with any request for those files.

The warning message itself tells you how to fix this - use another domain for your static content. Or a subdomain, as long as you make sure you keep your main domain cookieless in that case.

Comment: yes, I understood that the solution is to move the files to a cookieless domain. What I need to know is why cookies did not get attached to javascript files during the request and only to css and image?

Comment: @Abdel: Perhaps the tool missed those requests. Got a link to the page in question so I could see for myself?

Comment: unfortunately no.. let me check again if the tool missed them out

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to follow the exact suggestion in the warning message you pasted in (serve your static assets from a completely different hostname on which you don't set cookies). But in modern browsers you now also have the option of setting the [crossorigin="anonymous"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) attribute on the relevant elements, which will prevent cookies from being sent for the matching requests. You will need to combine this with returning an `access-control-allow-origin: YOUR-ORIGIN-HERE.com` header in your static asset responses.