# How to respect "Serve static content from a cookieless domain" page speed rule in IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, iis, pagespeed

How to respect "Serve static content from a cookieless domain" page speed rule in IIS6?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To create a cookieless site (or subdomain, which is a very common best-practice) in IIS6/IIS7/IIS7.5 is simple : you need to tell the website that you are not to use cookies :) **Which means in IIS terms, not to use a session**.

This can be achieved in IIS6/IIS7 via two ways.

1. Modifying the Web.config file (my personal recommendation)
2. Using the IIS Manager GUI to find the setting and changing it.

#### IMPORTANT

Before you do any testing, you **must must must** clear all cookies (or all cookies for the domain u are testing) otherwise, they will get passed along even if u have done all the steps.

#### 1. Via Config File

You need to [define the session state to off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx).

```
<system.web>
        <sessionState cookieName="What_ever" mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

*NOTE: Please note that the attribute cookieless (true|false) does NOT mean 'send cookies/do not sent cookies). That's for using sessions with/without cookies ... and passes some cookie guid into the url instead (if set to true).*

#### 2. Via Gui

[image]

[image]

Hope this Helps (i assume u know how to test that no cookies are working/not working...)

Comment: Thank you a lot I will create a new web application in order to that that.

Comment: both answers are valid but you I guess you invest more than Sam152 It's why I valid your answer. Thanks you All

Comment: This does not sound right. Setting sessionState mode to off does not turn of cookies. You can still set cookies with that setting on your web pages. We have been doing this in production for quite a while.

Comment: Off == Not Enabled. To -really- test this setting, make sure u connect to the website via Incognito/Private browsing, so no cookies are sent across on the FIRST request.

Comment: @Pure.Krome You've blanked out the site name in most of the images but not the Title on the right pane. Granted this was posted 3+ years ago, but thought you might like to know.

Comment: Ta - fixed. Can u remove your comment now, so not to hint at SO history changes...

Answer (score 8):

What this means is that your content needs to come from a domain that has no cookies attached to it. StackOverflow.com is an example of a site that does this. You will notice that all SO's **static content** comes from a domain called `sstatic.net`.

```
http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css
http://sstatic.net/js/master.js
```

This is so that the client and the server don't have to waste resources on actually parsing and handling cookie data. The good news is, you can use a sub-domain, assuming that you set your cookie path correctly.

**Yahoo Best Practices for Speeding Up
Your Web Site**

> Use Cookie-free Domains for Components
>
> When the browser makes a request for a
>   static image and sends cookies
>   together with the request, the server
>   doesn't have any use for those
>   cookies. So they only create network
>   traffic for no good reason. You should
>   make sure static components are
>   requested with cookie-free requests.
>   Create a subdomain and host all your
>   static components there. If your
>   domain is www.example.org, you can
>   host your static components on
>   static.example.org. However, if you've
>   already set cookies on the top-level
>   domain example.org as opposed to
>   www.example.org, then all the requests
>   to static.example.org will include
>   those cookies. In this case, you can
>   buy a whole new domain, host your
>   static components there, and keep this
>   domain cookie-free. Yahoo! uses
>   yimg.com, YouTube uses ytimg.com,
>   Amazon uses images-amazon.com and so
>   on.
>
> Another benefit of hosting static
>   components on a cookie-free domain is
>   that some proxies might refuse to
>   cache the components that are
>   requested with cookies. On a related
>   note, if you wonder if you should use
>   example.org or www.example.org for
>   your home page, consider the cookie
>   impact. Omitting www leaves you no
>   choice but to write cookies to
>   *.example.org, so for performance reasons it's best to use the www
>   subdomain and write the cookies to
>   that subdomain.

Comment: Cookies might be required by your web application, if they are, disabling them is not a good idea, is they aren't no cookies will be set anyway and this step wont apply to you.

Comment: @Christophe Debove - I've added a new answer to help you through the steps to making a cooklieless site in IIS.

Comment: @Christophe, You do not need to set anything to be `cookie less`, browser does this thing itself, when you are making `request` to any component which is located on `some other domain`, browser does not send any cookie with the request for some `security` reasons. and thus your requests become cookie less.

Comment: yeap of course thank you, it was implicit and not explicit it was why I was I little bit confused

Comment: @Zain Shaikh : can u please elaborate on your comment? Because I don't understand what you mean, and based upon my answer, it disagrees with your comment. My answer is targeting server configurations. Are you referring to client side configurations (which does agree with your comments -> no browser settings are required BUT you can tweak your browsers to never accept cookies). The question is targeting server configurations, though.

Comment: ok so I was I little bit confused with the process of cookie, I understood if the domain is different so the cookies are not send, like I said un my comment at the top of the page both of question are valid and it's why I vote up for both but I wich the configuration for IIS too. Even if I know in my case it's not necesary. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

create subdomain ( for example `static.example.com` ) and store all static content(images, css, js) here