# Slow performance when simultaneously launching jQuery .load

Tags: jquery, simultaneous

Occasionally my app needs to populate multiple content areas via simultaneous `jQuery .load()` calls.

Despite the content areas loading in under 100ms, the more simultaneous requests in place, the slower the content is displayed on the document.  Sometimes this can be as long as 10-15 seconds for 6 content areas.

Loads are initiated as follows:

```
$("#MyDiv1").load("/My/Controller/Action/1");
$("#MyDiv2").load("/My/Controller/Action/2");
$("#MyDiv3").load("/My/Controller/Action/3");
...
```

Any suggestions on how to combat this bottleneck would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using in the web server? PHP, ASP.NET, RoR?

Comment: The application is written on the ASP.NET MVC 3 framework and it's hosted on IIS7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET handles one request at a time under the same Session. So the second request won't run until the first one has completed. That's to avoid threading issues. You should see some improvement if you use Sessionless controllers.

Check out this link:

[What are some scenario's of having a Session-less Controller in ASP.NET MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139428/what-are-some-scenarios-of-having-a-session-less-controller-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Comment: This is very helpful. I do utilise sessions in my application (I have a managed SessionManager static which holds some app wide variables) - is there an alternative?

Comment: Would changing the Controller into an AsyncController address this problem?

Comment: @Nick do these specific calls use Session? If not, try moving them to a Sessionless controller. Are they modifying data? If not you can mark the sessionless controller as ReadOnly.

Comment: @Nick AsyncController won't do it. It just delegates the work to a separate thread pool freeing the IIS thread pool to handle other requests. The session issue still occurs.

Comment: I have decorated my controller with [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] as the session variables only need to be read and not written to. Should I continue to inherit from Controller or is there any value in changing to AsyncController so the work takes place on another thread?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because of the way javascript works. It wont wait to finish loading content 1 before it starts to load content 2 and 3 so it will all start to load at the same time.. So you should create some kind of que.

something like:

```
load array = new array()
array[array.length+1]= "/My/Controller/Action/1";  
array[array.length+1]= "/My/Controller/Action/2";  
array[array.length+1]= "/My/Controller/Action/3";  
loadContent();   
function loadContent()    
{
$("#MyDiv").load(array[0] function(){
        array.shift();
       if(array.length>0)
          loadContent() ; 
    });
}
```

note that is is not tested but it should give you a good ideer of what you can do

Answer (score 1):

Try to cascade the calls

```
$('#div1').load('...', function() {
    $('#div2').load('...', function() {
        $('#div3').load('...', function() {
            ....
        });
    });
});
```