# Cookieless sub domain

Tags: asp.net, cookies, dns, subdomain

I have one dome name. www.abc.com

and i want to speedup all images an d static content from cookies domain.

what i require to do with that?

i want to create new sub domain with name static.abc.com but that time also cookie coming with both domain.

i am user dotnet panel for hosting.

technology is .net

Comment: You don't want a "cookies domain", you want a cookie**less** domain.

Comment: but i required write cookie on www.abc.com it will automatically  take cookie for sub domain.

Comment: How does this have 2 votes for off-topic? Seems on-topic to me.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105149/how-to-respect-serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain-page-speed-rule-in/4105649#4105649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a cookie, set it's `Domain` property to `".abc.com"`, that way the cookie will be shared by both the `www.abc.com` and `static.abc.com` subdomains.

Comment: i don't want to cookie shared with other or static domain.

Comment: @AjmeraInfo: Then I misunderstood the question. If you don't want to share the cookies then you simply avoid setting the `Domain` property.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to accomplish this.  You could set the cookie for FQDN (fully-qualified domain name) of www.abc.com, but this would restrict the cookies to *just* www.abc.com.  This may be stricter than you want.

The more common solution it to register a completely separate domain for cookieless hosting.  This is used by many websites already.

- Google uses gstatic.com
- Facebook uses twimg.com (I think)
- Yahoo uses yimg.com (I think)
- EBay uses ebaystatic.com
- etc.